# Function is defined in external js script but not in react

Tags: reactjs

I just want to integrate the dacast api and trying to use their javascript script and in script dacast method is defined and how can i use this method in react since it is not defined in react?

```
import useScript from "./customHooks/useScript";

function App() {

  useScript("https://player.dacast.com/js/player.js?contentId=1552_f_297509");

  const loadPlayer = () => {
    var CONTENT_ID = "1552_f_297509"
    var myPlayer = dacast(CONTENT_ID, 'myDiv', {
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    });
  }



  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello.</h1>
      <div id="myDiv" onLoad={loadPlayer}></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You could add `script` tag with `src` pointing to the script which you want to import. Do this in your `index.html` and then that script object would be available in your React Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The **onLoad** event listener should be placed at created **script** tag, not at your **myDiv** tag. Since the **loadPlayer** method will be called once the script is completely loaded.
2. You should use **window["dacast"]** due to the **dacast** instance being loaded globally.
3. Please use this **useScript** custom hooks:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = ({ contentId, onLoad }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `//player.dacast.com/js/player.js?contentId=${contentId}`;
    script.onload = onLoad
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [contentId, onLoad]);
};

export default useScript;
```

4. Finally, implement the codes in the component like this:

```
import useScript from './useScript';
// you can change the contentId with yours;
const CONTENT_ID = "a1fca344-24e6-1490-5955-5e9e821c54a8-vod-1bc74c6f-3b77-6289-5ba9-54a70ae490f4"

function App() {
  const loadPlayer = () => {
    window["dacast"](CONTENT_ID, 'myDiv', {
      width: 350,
      height: 200
    });
  }

  useScript({
    contentId: CONTENT_ID,
    onLoad: loadPlayer
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      App
      <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to hear. Don't forget to accept this answer as an "accepted answer" if you think the solution solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your solution is accepted as its worked for me

Comment: would you please recommend me some live streaming platforms to integrate with my website. As my requirement is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216713/i-am-looking-forward-to-integrate-live-streaming-with-my-website

Comment: have you read this? https://www.dacast.com/blog/how-to-build-live-streaming-app/